Microsoft Graph API: oddity with searching a user by identity
I'm using Microsoft Graph API, and while trying to search a user there by issuerAssignedId, I got a strange exception if a colon symbol (":") is in the string to be compared with it.
Searching for users via graph explorer with a query like this works:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=identities&$filter=identities/any(id:id/issuer eq 'someTenantId' and id/issuerAssignedId eq 'someIssuerAssignedId')
Adding a colon sign anywhere in the string to be compares with issuerAssignedId, like this:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=identities&$filter=identities/any(id:id/issuer eq 'someTenantId' and id/issuerAssignedId eq 'someIssuerAssignedId:')
Gives me the following response:
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Request_BadRequest",
        "message": "Unsupported property or property value or combination of property and operation occured",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "xxxxxx",
            "request-id": "xxxxxx",
            "client-request-id": "xxxxxx"
        }
    }
}

This only happens with this exact field, the issuer field can be compared with a colon sign just fine.
To make things even more complicated, while using the actual piece of C# code accessing Graph API, to reproduce this behavior it's required to put not only a colon, but also an @ symbol into the string in any positions.
Is it some feature of Graph API I'm missing, or a peculiarity of this field, or a bug? Is it possible to do something about it except for not searching by colon sign at all?

According to the documentation, only alphanumeric characters and the symbols - or _ are allowed.
If you need the symbol : to be support then the best way is to create a feedback and we can vote for it.
https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ebe2edae-97d1-ec11-a7b5-0022481f3c80

Documentation claims that this value can be an email, which be definition contains @ symbol, and : is the only symbol causing this crypting error message.
